# Permission Denied When Making Request to GCP Video Intelligence API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

so I am able to make a valid request to the video intelligence api with the sample video given in the quickstart. https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/getting-started I have tried many different ways of authenticating to the api as well. The API token I am using was created from the Credentials page in the console. There are no options to tie it to the video api so I figured it should automatically work. The API has been enabled on my account.

```
export TOKEN="foobar"
curl -XPOST -s -k -H"Content-Type: application/json" "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1beta1/videos:annotate?key=$TOKEN" --data '{"inputUri": "gs://custom-bucket/IMG_3591.mov", "features": ["LABEL_DETECTION"]}'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

curl -XPOST -s -k -H"Content-Type: application/json" "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1beta1/videos:annotate?key=$TOKEN" --data '{"inputUri": "gs://cloud-ml-sandbox/video/chicago.mp4", "features": ["LABEL_DETECTION"]}'
{
  "name": "us-east1.18013173402060296928"
}
```

Update:

I set the file as public and it worked. But I need to access this as private, so I gave the service account access to the file and tried to get the API key like suggested.

```
export TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
curl -XPOST -s -k -H"Content-Type: application/json" "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1beta1/videos:annotate?key=$TOKEN" --data '{"inputUri": "gs://custom-bucket/IMG_3591.mov", "features":["LABEL_DETECTION"]}'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems like the token returned by this print-access-token function does not work. I do have an API key, but it does not have access to the bucket and I don't see a way to give an API key access.

Update 2:

So it looks like we were setting our token wrong. We were following this example https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/analyze-labels#videointelligence-label-file-protocol which is where we got the apiKey=$TOKEN from. But it looks like we needed to set the Bearer Header. We did try this at first but we were having the first issue of not having access to the bucket. So thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Video Intelligence service is unable to access the file on your Cloud storage bucket because of lack of permissions. Since the API uses the permissions of the service account token being passed, you will need to grant your service account permissions to read the file in the GCS bucket or the entire GCS bucket itself.

**Long version**

The access token you pass should correspond to an IAM service account key. The service account will belong to a project (where you need to enable the Video intelligence API access) and the service account should have permissions to access the GCS bucket you're trying to access.

Each such service account has an associated email id in the form `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

In Cloud console, you can go to the Cloud storage bucket/file and grant `Reader` permissions for the IAM service account email address. There is no need to make this bucket public.

If you use `gsutil`, you can run the following equivalent command:

```
gsutil acl ch -u SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com:READ gs://custom-bucket/IMG_3591.mov`
```

I confirmed this myself with an IAM service account that I created in my project and used this to invoke the video intelligence API. The file was not made public, but granted Reader permissions only to the service account.

I used gcloud to activate the service account and fetch the access token, although you can do this manually as well using the google OAuth APIs:

- `gcloud auth activate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY.json`
- `export TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"`

The steps for creating the IAM service account using gcloud are in the [same page](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/getting-started#set_up_authorization).

Answer (score 2):

I can repro this issue. I believe the problem is that you don't have proper permission setup for your video file in your gs bucket. To test out this hypothesis try sharing it publicly (checkbox next to the blob in Google Storage) and then run the request again.