# Error in Request to Google Video Intelligence API

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I have been trying to send a request to the Google Video Intelligence API for SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION (in node.js), but I keep running into the same error:

> ERROR: { Error: Request contains an invalid argument.
>       at /Users/paulsteenkiste/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:569:15
>     code: 3,
>     metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
>     note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }

I tried to dive into that client.js file listed in the error, but it was not very illuminating. Here is the code that yields this error:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp({
    serviceAccount: "./service-account.json",
    apiKey: "<API key>",
    databaseURL: "<My Database>"
});

// Imports the Google Cloud Video Intelligence library
const Video = require('@google-cloud/video-intelligence');

// Instantiates a client
const video = Video();

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("<My email>", "<My password>")
    .then(function(user) {

    // The GCS filepath of the video to analyze
    const gcsUri = '<File location>';

    const request = {
      inputUri: gcsUri,
      features: ["SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION"]
    };

    // Human-readable likelihoods
    const likelihoods = ['UNKNOWN', 'VERY_UNLIKELY', 'UNLIKELY', 'POSSIBLE', 'LIKELY', 'VERY_LIKELY'];

    // Detects unsafe content
    video.annotateVideo(request)
      .then((results) => {
        const operation = results[0];
        console.log('Waiting for operation to complete...');
        return operation.promise();
      })
      .then((results) => {
        // Gets unsafe content
        const safeSearchResults = results[0].annotationResults[0].safeSearchAnnotations;
        console.log('Safe search results:');
        safeSearchResults.forEach((result) => {
          console.log(`Time: ${result.timeOffset / 1e6}s`);
          console.log(`\tAdult: ${likelihoods[result.adult]}`);
          console.log(`\tSpoof: ${likelihoods[result.spoof]}`);
          console.log(`\tMedical: ${likelihoods[result.medical]}`);
          console.log(`\tViolent: ${likelihoods[result.violent]}`);
          console.log(`\tRacy: ${likelihoods[result.racy]}`);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });
```

(Note that this is essentially copied and pasted from Google's docs at https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/analyze-safesearch). The service-account.json is the file I downloaded when I created the service account, and it is in the same folder as the above file. I do not think it is necessary to do that firebase authentication, but I wanted to make sure that wasn't the issue. I have enabled the API and have full access to the project, so neither of those are the issue.

I believe the problem is coming from the service account somehow, but whatever I try the same error shows up. Some of the things that I have tried:

1. Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS from the terminal
2. Giving that service account "Suite Domain-wide Delegation"
3. Making the file public
4. Doing the "gsutil" command recommended by the answer here: [Permission Denied When Making Request to GCP Video Intelligence API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441055/permission-denied-when-making-request-to-gcp-video-intelligence-api)

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue in a recent project, and found out that it was due to submitting an `https://` URI when Google Cloud Services expected a `gs://` URI. The `Error: Request contains an invalid argument.` makes me pretty sure that this is the issue.

The simplist fix would be to directly modify the url you are passing on to the API call.

`const gcsUri = '<File location>'.replace('https://storage.googleapis.com/', 'gs://')`

And yes, most of their APIs require the files to be in their own cloud storage. If you are trying to process a video located elsewhere, you will likely first need to copy it into their cloud storage.